# Separate Scaling for Multiple Print Areas on Single Worksheet

Tags: printing, phpexcel, scaling

I have one sheet in Excel with multiple print areas. Scaling is set to 'Fit on One Page'. The print looks great for the larger area, but the smaller print area uses the same scaling and as a result looks unnecessarily small.

Is there some way to get Excel to intelligently scale each area without having these areas be on separate sheets?

Comment: Does MS Excel support this? Can you create a spreadsheet using MS Excel that does what you want?

Comment: That's just it, I don't know. I'm working directly with the worksheet but it doesn't seem possible to scale print areas distinctly.